# summation of a series that depends on euler totient function and binomial cofficent

Tags: combinations, totient-function

I am really stuck at a problem that asks me to find the following summation 
$$
\sum_{i\mid n}\phi(i)\binom{n/i}{k}
$$
I would really appreciate if someone can provide me with a solution for the same .
Where n/i is floor(n/i)

Comment: Does the sum happen to be over $i\mid n$? Please use [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/tex-latex-mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to make your question more readable and understandable.

Comment: Do you mean $\sum_{\substack{i\mid n }} \varphi(i){n/i \choose k}$?

Comment: @user69: I have edited your question. Please check to see it is what you intended.

Comment: Where did you find this problem?